# column vector element-wise multiplied by matrix

Tags: r

**Large data** of a column vector multiplied by a matrix (same row numbers). Is there any way to vectorize the operation? If possible, please avoid loop.

```
a<-matrix(2,nrow =5)
b<-matrix(c(1:5),ncol=3,nrow=5)

a
         [,1]
    [1,]    2
    [2,]    2
    [3,]    2
    [4,]    2
    [5,]    2

b
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    1    1    1
    [2,]    2    2    2
    [3,]    3    3    3
    [4,]    4    4    4
    [5,]    5    5    5
```

Desired output

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    2    2
[2,]    4    4    4
[3,]    6    6    6
[4,]    8    8    8
[5,]   10   10   10
```

Comment: This would seem to be answered by `c(a)*b
`